# How to solve KeyError in dfs, bfs

Tags: python, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

I was trying to create bfs, dfs programs by using the following python code. Unfortunately having this error...... anybody plz help for me

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:...\1260.py", line 35, in 
> print(dfs(graph, 1))
> File "D:...\1260.py", line 30, in dfs
> stack.extend(graph[node])
> KeyError: 4

```
graph = {
    1: [2, 3, 4],
    2: [4],
    3: [4]
}

def bfs(graph, start_node):
    visit = list()
    queue = list()

    queue.append(start_node)
    while queue:
        node = queue.pop(0)
        if node not in visit:
            visit.append(node)
            queue.extend(graph[node])
            
    return visit

def dfs(graph, start_node):
    visit = list()
    stack = list()

    stack.append(start_node)

    while stack:
        node = stack.pop()
        if node not in visit:
            visit.append(node)
            stack.extend(graph[node])

    return visit

if '__main__' == __name__:
    print(dfs(graph, 1))
    print(bfs(graph, 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
stack.extend(graph[node])
```

You have no `node` key in the `graph`.

```py
try:
    stack.extend(graph[node])
except KeyError:
    print(f"Unexpected node: {node}")
```